# Inconsistent metal texture

Tags: texturing, materials, image, edges, lighting

Everywhere on the object the texture is nice flat and consistent, but in this part it is quite rough and I don't know what to do with it. I tried almost everything, even modeling it again. The geometry is everywhere the same.

Part of the inconsistent metal texture:

[image: Part of the inconsistent metal texture]

[image]

Comment: I think you just need to [delete geometry beyond the mirror-axes](https://blend-exchange.com/b/1BXsvQa8/). Otherwise the surface is z-fighting its own reflection. ( Mirroring while still in the lo-poly state is also more conventional)

Comment: @RobinBetts - It is perfect now! Thanks a lot man! Can I ask, how exactly did you deleted geometry behind the mirror? I am really into learning something new and useful in Blender.

Comment: Hi, Matěj ! I've posted an answer describing the sort of steps I took with this (new-to-me) file.

Comment: @RobinBetts - I don't know how to properly say how grateful I am. Thank you so much. I learned a lot of new stuff by this, so really appreciate it! Have a nice day Mr. Blendmagician!

Answer (score 1):

In response to your comment.. these were my steps.

[image]

- (1) Mute all the modifiers, to see what basic geometry we have.
- (2) Note that the geometry is on both sides of the symmetry lines. A *Mirror* modifier reflects both ways across it, unless 'Bisect' is checked, so this will result in overlapping geometry.
- (2, cont.) Attempt to  <kbd>Alt</kbd> select the edge-loops at 12 and 6 o'clock. This fails to select all the way round, on good-looking topology, arousing suspicions. Tweak and drop the vertices where the loop selection stops, find duplicate vertices.
- (2, cont.) See if <kbd>M</kbd> Merge > 'By Distance' gets rid of the vertices. Info bar tells me 43 vertices removed, loop-selection now works. <kbd>H</kbd> hide a few faces in Edit Mode to check for internal/duplicate faces, etc. Seems OK.
- (3) OK. -  <kbd>V</kbd> rip the edge-loop selection, and drag left...

[image]

- (4) Do the same with a loop-selection at 3 o'clock, dragging down.  <kbd>L</kbd> hover over the mesh-islands to select, and delete, leaving 1/4 of the mesh.
- (5) Switch on 'Axes' in Object tab,  Viewport Display panel, to see the orientation of the object. X,Y,Z uneven. Inspect Object Scale in the properties panel. Note non-uniform object-level scale. No. This can have undesirable side-effects. (Always scale in Edit Mode, while modelling).  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> > Apply scale, to correct.
- (6) Seems clean. OK. *Mirror* in X and Y, and *Subdivide*.

The only concern left is that the radial loops in the circle are not evenly distributed. Looking out for uneven shading / apparent curvature under subdivision. However, when shaded, looks perfectly acceptable. But may have to bear this in mind if fitting other circles to this one.

[image]